# Android ScrollView subelement position

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I've a ScrollView and i would like to Scroll To one sub element (a Relative View),
I know how to scroll into a X/Y position, but how to know the position of my Relative View inside Scroll View ?
Or Maybe it's possible to directly Scroll into this Relative View ?

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
....
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/box"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
....
</ScrollView>
```

I want to Scroll to @+id/box. Is it possible?

Comment: i don't believe there is such way to scroll by id, but you can use ScrollTo() function and set there your Layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scroll to a specific element, i ".getHeight()" from all previous element and i add topMargin too, and then scroll to this position

To get topMargin :

```
MarginLayoutParams vlpBox = (MarginLayoutParams) box1.getLayoutParams();
vlpBox.topMargin
```

To get real Height(not wrap_content) :

```
View.getHeight()
```

it's a workaround, i don't know if a better solution exist.